# Creating a pointer to a HWND pointer in C++ for creating a child webview

Tags: c++, winapi, webview, sciter

I am using `webview.h` and trying to create a webview as a child to my application.

This is the `webview_create` function:

```
WEBVIEW_API webview_t webview_create(int debug, void *wnd) {
   return new webview::webview(debug, wnd);
}
```

They are describing my problem in this issue:

https://github.com/webview/webview/issues/386

When I try to create the webview, it either crashes my application immediately, or resizes my entire application and crashes soon after (but loads the website).

In the GitHub issue, the problem was resolved by *passing a pointer to the HWND variable*

What I tried:

```
HWND parent = self.get_element_hwnd(false);
webview::webview w(false, parent);


HWND parent = self.get_element_hwnd(false);
webview::webview w(false, &parent);


HWND parent = self.get_element_hwnd(false);
HWND *pp = &parent;
webview::webview w(false, pp);


HWND parent = self.get_element_hwnd(false);
HWND *pp = &parent;
webview::webview w(false, &pp);
```

I thought passing the HWND like `&parent` should work, but it doesn't.
Basically, I am guessing at this point. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `self` here? I understand this is some kind of sciter thing but if you look at the window handle you are getting back, in Spy++ say or just by inspecting it with various Win32 calls, is `get_element_hwnd` giving you the window handle you expect?

Comment: `self` is `sciter::dom::element` here is the doc of the `get_element_hwnd` https://sciter.com/sdk/doc.api/html/classsciter_1_1dom_1_1element.html#ab7eb72a021c4b8bc3a21f40efb20f6b2 it basically calls 
`inline SCDOM_RESULT SCAPI SciterGetElementHwnd(HELEMENT he, HWINDOW* p_hwnd, BOOL rootWindow) { return SAPI()->SciterGetElementHwnd(he,p_hwnd,rootWindow); }`

Not quite sure on what to expect as a window handle. Oddly enough, when I call the webview.run() function, the webview works but it 'takes over' my application in fullscreen. https://github.com/webview/webview/blob/master/webview.h#L1141

Comment: It seems like the webview class is ignoring the window handle you pass it. Either you are getting a bad window handle back from sciter or that webview class has a bug in it. I don't know which but the webview code does not instill me with a lot of confidence. What platforms do you need to support? You could just use one of Microsoft's native web views if you only care about windows or you could use CEF otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried to make `pp` pointer non local (eg biltin into structure/object or global)?

Comment: I tried that @DanielSęk it yelds the same result.